# Using gulp for compiling of changed files only

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I have lots of .jade, .styl and .coffee files resided in different subfolders.

I’d like to compile only changed files when they are changed.
I’m using `gulp` and I’ve come up to the following pattern:

```
var watch = require('gulp-watch'),

watch(['app/**/*.styl'], function (e) {
    gulp.src(e.path)
        .pipe(stylus({use: nib()}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'))
```

However this pattern stores compiled file into the root of ./app folder, but not to the folder where the source file resides.
I’ve tried lots of stuff and all in vain.
The problem is that there is a lack of documentation and samples for gulp-watch and others.

Could anybody tell me how to store compiled file to the its source’s folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you pass `e.path` (i.e. the full path of every changed file) as a glob pattern to `gulp.src()`. This means that your glob pattern does not actually contain a glob (like `*` or `**`), in which case the directory where the file is located is used as the default value for the [`base` option](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#optionsbase) to `gulp.src()`. When the files are then written with `gulp.dest()` that `base` option causes the entire directory structure to get stripped.

The solution is to use the [streaming variant of `gulp-watch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch#usage)  instead of the callback variant ...

```
gulp.src('app/**/*.styl')
  .pipe(watch('app/**/*.styl'))
  .pipe(stylus({use: nib()}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'));
```

... or provide an appropriate `base` option to the callback variant:

```
watch(['app/**/*.styl'], function (e) {
  gulp.src(e.path, {base: 'app'})
    .pipe(stylus({use: nib()}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'));
});
```

Comment: Your solution rebuilds all the files app/**/*.styl, but I need only one, changed.

Comment: It only does so on the first run. After that only those files that are changed are rewritten. If that doesn't work for you, I've edited my answer to include a callback variant that doesn't have that drawback.